# goroutine consuming the same line more than once

Tags: multithreading, go, goroutine

currently i have a scenario where i have huge file (for example im going to say 500k lines of text) and the idea is to use worker (threads) to process them by 100 each thread. after running my code, i still wonder why the goroutines consume the same line more than once? im guessing it's racing to get the job done.

here's my code

```
package main

import (
     "log"
     "bufio"
     "fmt"
     "encoding/csv"
     "encoding/json"
     "io"
     "os"
     "sync"
)

type IMDBDataModel struct {
     Color                  string `json:"color"`
     DirectorName           string `json:"director_name"`
     NumCriticForReviews    string `json:"num_critic_for_reviews"`
     Duration               string `json:"duration"`
     DirectorFacebookLikes  string `json:"director_facebook_likes"`
     Actor3FacebookLikes    string `json:"actor_3_facebook_likes"`
     Actor2Name             string `json:"actor_2_name"`
     Actor1FacebookLikes    string `json:"actor_1_facebook_likes"`
     Gross                  string `json:"gross"`
     Genre                  string `json:"genres"`
     Actor1Name             string `json:"actor_1_name"`
     MovieTitle             string `json:"movie_title"`
     NumVotedUser           string `json:"num_voted_users"`
     CastTotalFacebookLikes string `json:"cast_total_facebook_likes"`
     Actor3Name             string `json:"actor_3_name"`
     FaceNumberInPoster     string `json:"facenumber_in_poster"`
     PlotKeywords           string `json:"plot_keywords"`
     MovieIMDBLink          string `json:"movie_imdb_link"`
     NumUserForReviews      string `json:"num_user_for_reviews"`
     Language               string `json:"language"`
     Country                string `json:"country"`
     ContentRating          string `json:"content_rating"`
     Budget                 string `json:"budget"`
     TitleYear              string `json:"title_year"`
     Actor2FacebookLikes    string `json:"actor_2_facebook_likes"`
     IMDBScore              string `json:"imdb_score"`
     AspectRatio            string `json:"aspect_ratio"`
     MovieFacebookLikes     string `json:"movie_facebook_likes"`
}

var iterated int64
var out []*IMDBDataModel

func populateString(input []IMDBDataModel, out []*IMDBDataModel, wg *sync.WaitGroup) {
     for _ , data := range input {          
          out = append(out, &data)
     }     
     wg.Done()
}

func consumeData(input <-chan *IMDBDataModel, wg *sync.WaitGroup){
     defer wg.Done()
     for data := range input {          
          iterated++          
          fmt.Printf("%d : %s\n", iterated, data.MovieTitle)
          out = append(out, data)
     }
     fmt.Println("output size : ", len(out))

}

func processCSV(path string) (imdbList []IMDBDataModel){
     csvFile, _ := os.Open(path)
     reader := csv.NewReader(bufio.NewReader(csvFile))

     for {          
          line, error := reader.Read()
          if error == io.EOF {
               break
          } else if error != nil {
               log.Fatal(error)
          }
          imdbList = append(imdbList, 
               IMDBDataModel{
                    Color: line[0],
                    DirectorName: line[1],
                    NumCriticForReviews : line[2],
                    Duration: line[3],
                    DirectorFacebookLikes: line[4],
                    Actor3FacebookLikes: line[5],
                    Actor2Name: line[6],
                    Actor1FacebookLikes: line[7],
                    Gross: line[8],
                    Genre: line[9],
                    Actor1Name: line[10],
                    MovieTitle: line[11],
                    NumVotedUser: line[12],
                    CastTotalFacebookLikes: line[13],
                    Actor3Name: line[14],
                    FaceNumberInPoster: line[15],
                    PlotKeywords: line[16],
                    MovieIMDBLink: line[17],
                    NumUserForReviews: line[18],
                    Language: line[19],
                    Country: line[20],
                    ContentRating: line[21],
                    Budget: line[22],
                    TitleYear: line[23],
                    Actor2FacebookLikes: line[24],
                    IMDBScore: line[25],
                    AspectRatio: line[26],
                    MovieFacebookLikes: line[27],
               },
          )          
     }
     imdbJson, err := json.Marshal(imdbList)
     if err != nil {
          log.Println(imdbJson)
     }

     return 
}

func main() {     
     imdbList := processCSV("movie_metadata.csv")     
     imdbChannel  := make(chan *IMDBDataModel, 100) // buffer

     var wg sync.WaitGroup
     for i := 0; i < 5;i++ {
          wg.Add(1)
          go consumeData(imdbChannel,&wg)     
     }

     for _ ,task := range imdbList {          
          imdbChannel <- &task               
     }

     close(imdbChannel)     
     wg.Wait()

     // for _, item := range out {
     //      fmt.Println(item.MovieTitle)
     // }

     fmt.Println("Total Channel :", len(imdbChannel)) 
     fmt.Println("Total IMDB :", len(imdbList))
     fmt.Println("Total Data: ", len(out))
     fmt.Println("Iterated : ", iterated)
     fmt.Println("Goroutines finished..")


}
```

EDITED:
after few suggestions on adding mutex and another channel, this is the modified consume function

```
func consumeData(input <-chan *IMDBDataModel, output chan *IMDBDataModel, wg *sync.WaitGroup) {
    defer wg.Done()
    for data := range input {
        iterated++
        // outLock.Lock()
        // out = append(out, data)
        // outLock.Unlock()
        output <- data
    }
}
```

however still consuming the same line (race occured) more than once.

```
....
My Date with Drew 
My Date with Drew 
My Date with Drew 
My Date with Drew 
My Date with Drew 
Total Channel : 0
Total IMDB : 5044
Total Data:  4944
Iterated :  5000
Goroutines finished..
```

Comment: Compile (or run) with the `-race` flag to see where it's broken. I guess it's the append to the `out` slice.

Comment: Looking at the code, there appears to be a race in `consumeData` at the line `out = append(out, data)`. Protect this access using a mutex.

Answer (score 0):

You issues is with:

```
var out []*IMDBDataModel

func consumeData(input <-chan *IMDBDataModel, wg *sync.WaitGroup){
     defer wg.Done()
     for data := range input {          
          iterated++          
          fmt.Printf("%d : %s\n", iterated, data.MovieTitle)
          out = append(out, data)
     }
     fmt.Println("output size : ", len(out))

}
```

You are appending to "out" from multiple threads:

try adding a lock around the places you write to "out" like this:

```
var out []*IMDBDataModel
var outLock sync.Mutex

func consumeData(input <-chan *IMDBDataModel, wg *sync.WaitGroup){
     defer wg.Done()
     for data := range input {          
          iterated++          
          fmt.Printf("%d : %s\n", iterated, data.MovieTitle)
          outLock.Lock()
          out = append(out, &data)
          outLock.Unlock()
     }
     outLock.Lock()
     fmt.Println("output size : ", len(out))
     outLock.Unlock()

}
```

Comment: Or write to a channel, and have a single goroutine that reads from that channel and writes to out, aka fan-in. With a buffered channel and sufficient physical threads this should give better performance than a mutex.

Comment: yep, good point.  And given that this problem, as it sits, should not be parallelized given what it does.  I opted to suggest the easier to comprehend version.

Comment: @DavidBudworth I tried both solution, while the mutex and writing to separate channel still contains many duplicates. I wonder what did i miss this time?